# Maximum call stack size exceeded with Select, AutoComplete Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hello everyone I'm testing all the MUI components. Both Select and Autocomplete they give me the same error. For select I copied the exact component from the docs and got the same error.

I'm using tsx.

MUI version: 5.10.15

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: React instrumentation encountered an error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

```js
import { Autocomplete, Stack, TextField } from '@mui/material'

const MuiAutocomplete = () => {
    const skills = ['HTML', 'JS', 'CSS', 'React']

    return (
        <Stack spacing={2} width="250px">
            <Autocomplete
                options={skills}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="skills" />}
            />
        </Stack>
    )
}

export default MuiAutocomplete
```

Just Tested Accordion Component. Same thing.

Comment: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/35288). Here you can more analytics like versions etc.

Comment: Okay I found the problem Google Chrome React Developer Tools Extension. I disabled it and now it works perfectly. Any fixes for it?